# how to subtract a Date from a Date in database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datediff

i am using this query Select (DateRented-DateReturned) as 'Left now' but the problem is if the DateRented is 2015-8-31 and the DateReturned is 2015-9-31 the output is -100. but the expected output is 30days

Comment: I should note that 2015-09-31 is not a valid date, because September only has 30 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `datediff()` instead:

```
select datediff(DateReturned, DateRented)
. . .
```

MySQL can do weird things with dates.  In a numeric context, it sometimes turns them into numbers, so instead of 2015-08-01, you get the integer 2,0150,801.  This appears to be what is happening in your case.